# How to scroll the page straight to the main content when the user start scrolling the page?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page with a full screen image at the top. the main content is just under the image. my goal is the page scroll straight to the main content when the user start scrolling the page.
How can I do this using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Amin52J/vtk60ov9/)**

```
$(document).one('scroll',function(){
    $('body, html').animate({scrollTop:$('#target').offset().top},200);
});
```